# Ejecutar función javascript desde html

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código html y quiero ejecutar una llamada a una función en java script.

```js
                function fnBuscaPacientesSeleccion(parmNomApeRut, parmPiso, parmCama, IdTurno) // esta se ejecuta cuando el usuario da clicnk en elboton
                {
                    var parametrosAjax = {
                        "NomApeRut": parmNomApeRut,
                        "Piso": parmPiso,
                        "Cama": parmCama,
                        "IdTurno": IdTurno
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(parametrosAjax),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetPacientesSeleccion", "Selecciona")',
                            success: function (pacientes) {
                                if (pacientes == null)
                                {
                                    var msgErr = "No se encontraron pacientes para dispensar"
                                    $('#DivPacientes').append(msgErr);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $.each(pacientes, function (idx, paciente) {
                                        var idBoton = "BtnPaciente_" + paciente.IdPaciente;
                                        var boton = '<div class="item">';
                                        boton += '<input type="checkbox" name="check" id=' + idBoton + ' value= ' + paciente.IdPaciente +'>';
                                        boton += '<label for="' + idBoton +'" class="contenido">';
                                        boton += '<p><strong>';
                                        boton += "Cama: " + paciente.CamaActual;
                                        boton += '</strong > </p > ';
                                        boton += '<p>' + paciente.FilterDatosPacienteDto.NombrePaciente + " " + paciente.FilterDatosPacienteDto.ApellidoPaterno + '</p>';
                                        boton += '</label>';
                                        boton += '</div>';
                                        $("#DivPacientes").append(boton);
                                        });
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                var msgErr = "No se enontraron resultados"
                                $('#DivPacientes').html(msgErr);
                            }
                        });
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="general_buscador">
        <div class="nombre_c">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre, Apellido, RUT" name="nombre" id="txtNombreApellidoRut" value="" class="nombre input_buscador jQKeyboard" />
        </div>
        <div class="pisocama_c">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Piso" name="piso" id="txtPiso" value="" class="piso input_buscador jQKeyboard" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Cama" name="cama" id="txtCama" value="" class="cama input_buscador jQKeyboard" />
        </div>
        <div class="botonera">
            <input type="button" name="limpiar" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar" class="boton">
            <input type="button" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="Buscar" class="boton" onclick="fnBuscaPacientesSeleccion()">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mi duda es ¿Cómo llamo a esta función desde el botón `buscar`?. Se que es algo básico, y que se usa la función `onclick`, pero **no se como pasarle los parámetros**, que en este caso serian `nombre`, `piso`, `cama`...

Comment: Desde HTML siempre podés usar esto para llamar funciones. ´<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">Buscar</a>´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro de la función puedes capturar los valores ingresados a los `input` de tu formulario, así:

```
function fnBuscaPacientesSeleccion(){
       var parmNomApeRut = $("#txtNombreApellidoRut").val();
       var parmPiso = $("#txtPiso").val();
       var parmCama = $("#txtCama").val();
       var IdTurno = 1;

                var parametrosAjax = {
                    "NomApeRut": parmNomApeRut,
                    "Piso": parmPiso,
                    "Cama": parmCama,
                    "IdTurno": IdTurno
                };
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(parametrosAjax),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetPacientesSeleccion", "Selecciona")',
                        success: function (pacientes) {
                            if (pacientes == null)
                            {
                                var msgErr = "No se encontraron pacientes para dispensar"
                                $('#DivPacientes').append(msgErr);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $.each(pacientes, function (idx, paciente) {
                                    var idBoton = "BtnPaciente_" + paciente.IdPaciente;
                                    var boton = '<div class="item">';
                                    boton += '<input type="checkbox" name="check" id=' + idBoton + ' value= ' + paciente.IdPaciente +'>';
                                    boton += '<label for="' + idBoton +'" class="contenido">';
                                    boton += '<p><strong>';
                                    boton += "Cama: " + paciente.CamaActual;
                                    boton += '</strong > </p > ';
                                    boton += '<p>' + paciente.FilterDatosPacienteDto.NombrePaciente + " " + paciente.FilterDatosPacienteDto.ApellidoPaterno + '</p>';
                                    boton += '</label>';
                                    boton += '</div>';
                                    $("#DivPacientes").append(boton);
                                    });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            var msgErr = "No se enontraron resultados"
                            $('#DivPacientes').html(msgErr);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Espero te sirva, saludos !

Comment: excelente estimado, muy buena idea. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Según yo te falta agregar el id del botón

```
 $("#id_del_boton").click(function fnBuscaPacientesSeleccion(parmNomApeRut, parmPiso, parmCama, IdTurno) // esta se ejecuta cuando el usuario da clicnk en elboton
        {
            var parametrosAjax = {
                "NomApeRut": parmNomApeRut,
                "Piso": parmPiso,
                "Cama": parmCama,
                "IdTurno": IdTurno
            };
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(parametrosAjax),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetPacientesSeleccion", "Selecciona")',
                    success: function (pacientes) {
                        if (pacientes == null)
                        {
                            var msgErr = "No se encontraron pacientes para dispensar"
                            $('#DivPacientes').append(msgErr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $.each(pacientes, function (idx, paciente) {
                                var idBoton = "BtnPaciente_" + paciente.IdPaciente;
                                var boton = '<div class="item">';
                                boton += '<input type="checkbox" name="check" id=' + idBoton + ' value= ' + paciente.IdPaciente +'>';
                                boton += '<label for="' + idBoton +'" class="contenido">';
                                boton += '<p><strong>';
                                boton += "Cama: " + paciente.CamaActual;
                                boton += '</strong > </p > ';
                                boton += '<p>' + paciente.FilterDatosPacienteDto.NombrePaciente + " " + paciente.FilterDatosPacienteDto.ApellidoPaterno + '</p>';
                                boton += '</label>';
                                boton += '</div>';
                                $("#DivPacientes").append(boton);
                                });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        var msgErr = "No se enontraron resultados"
                        $('#DivPacientes').html(msgErr);
                    }
                });
        });
```